# Where can I find Vagrant packages?

Tags: package-management, ppa, virtualization, vagrant

[Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) is a tool to build and manage virtual machines for developers.  It has a [getting started on Ubuntu](http://vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/setup/ubuntu.html) guide that contains iffy-looking suggestions like

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/bin/ruby  # wtf???
```

or installing RubyGems from source rather than from Ubuntu packages, and then using `gem install` to install vagrant itself.

I'm not feeling comfortable just following those instructions.  Is there perhaps a PPA?  Are there, perhaps, alternative tools that are packaged for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## 12.04

[Vagrant](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/vagrant) [image: install vagrant] 1.0.1 is now included in universe in 12.04 and you can install this via the Software Center.

Comment: I can't make up my mind if I should mark your answer as accepted now, or wait until 12.04 will actually be released.

Comment: The official packages are so old, it is better to download directly from vagrantup.com.

Answer (score 17):

Nowadays you can download self-contained .deb files from http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html

Not as good as a PPA, but at least you can introspect what files get installed where and remove the package cleanly.

Comment: Vagrant's failure to provide installation packages via a channel which allows for notification of future security problems is a concern.

Comment: I thought many PPA's were made by the community. Couldn't someone just maintain this?

Comment: Sure @JonathanLeaders and [this unofficial PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vagrant) from [Antonio Terceiro](https://launchpad.net/~terceiro) looks pretty updated.

Comment: That does look up to date, but unfortunately it also doesn't appear to be a ppa... what am I doing wrong? `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:terceiro/vagrant`

Answer (score -2):

There is nothing to worry about the instructions in this [getting started on Ubuntu](http://vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/setup/ubuntu.html) guide. Making a [soft link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to `/usr/bin/ruby1.8` does not harm your system in anyway. Just go ahead with the tutorial and install vagrant.To install vagrant you can use:

```
  sudo gem install vagrant
```

As far as i know there is no PPA available for vagrant. The best method to install it is using the gem.

If you are feeling any difficulties feel free to post it here

Comment: Did that, found out Vagrant refuses to work with virtualbox-ose and wants me to install the closed-source version.  Shrugged, uninstalled Vagrant.

Comment: "Thanks for wanting to use Vagrant! Unfortunately, this is not the way to install Vagrant anymore. We now make installers for the various operating systems Vagrant supports.

Vagrant is no longer distributed as a RubyGem.[...] Note that
the RubyGem version hasn't been updated in over a year and will no longer
receive any updates.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Ruby:

It's better to install it via Rubygems despite the website's recommendation of .deb installation.  The website seems to be a little behind on updates. The instructions of the vagrant gem seem more up-to-date: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant

If Bundler is installing a sub-1.0.0 version of the gem:

- put `gem 'vagrant'` above all other gems in your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`.
- if that still doesn't work, put `gem 'vagrant', '~> 1.0'` and run `bundle install`.

Sometimes bundler installs an old version of the `vagrant` gem if your other gems installed old versions of gems, like `json`.